# Accesibility for access modifiers

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Accessibility for access modifiers of JAVA

- Public
- Private
- Protected
- Default (No access modifier declared)

in

- Same Class
- Same Package
- Subclass
- Universe/Other Packages

I was looking for the answers on the internet for these as i had multiple answers. A video said non-declared access modifiers are public while i saw another written source saying non-declared access modifiers have no restriction in subclasses and other packages. Trying to confirm which is real.

Comment: Googling for "Java access modifiers" leads to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html as the first result. This page is on Oracle's Java tutorial. Oracle is the company behind Java. It's thus much more credible than any random Youtube video.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This would tell you how modifier works

Comment: I had an image at my dekstop,so shared it :)